# scrape a table in python not showing correct results as expected

Tags: python, web-scraping

need to scrape all the table data from rajya sabha website. however, instead of scraping from the url link the code scrapes the original table page by page

```
from selenium import webdriver
import chromedriver_binary
import os
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import time
import lxml



url = 'https://rsdebate.nic.in/simple-search?query=climate+change&sort_by=dc.identifier.sessionnumber_sort&order=asc&rpp=100&etal=0&start=0'

#url_call = f"https://rsdebate.nic.in/simple-search?query=climate+change&sort_by=dc.identifier.sessionnumber_sort&order=asc&rpp=100&etal=0&start={i}"
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')

table1 = soup.find('table', id='sam_table')
headers = []
for a in table1.find_all('th'):
    title = a.text
    headers.append(title)
    rsdata = pd.DataFrame(columns = headers)
    rsdata.to_csv('rs_debate_data.csv', mode ='a',index=False)
    
# Create a for loop to fill rajya sabha data
for k in range(0,96):
    url_call = f"https://rsdebate.nic.in/simple-search?query=climate+change&sort_by=dc.identifier.sessionnumber_sort&order=asc&rpp=100&etal=0&start={k}"
    page = requests.get(url_call)
    for j in table1.find_all('tr')[1:]:
        row_data = j.find_all('td')
        row = [i.text for i in row_data]
        length = len(rsdata)
        rsdata.loc[length] = row
        rsdata.to_csv('rs_debate_data.csv', mode ='a',index=False, header=False)
print(k)


# Export to csv

# Try to read csv
#rs_data = pd.read_csv('rs_debate_data.csv')
```

i was trying to scrape only rows related to keyword climate change in the debate title column of the table.

Answer (score 1):

```
for k in range(0,96):
    url_call = "..."
    page = requests.get(url_call)
    for j in table1.find_all('tr')[1:]:
```

This loop does a `find_all()` on the original `table1` results, not on the page it just fetched...